# No reputation for upvote given?, (not a daily cap)

Tags: support, community-wiki, specific-answer

i did get 17 up-votes for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746740/google-map-icons-with-visualrefresh/18531494#18531494)

but only got 145 reputation total for that answer, should it not be 185?
(17 * 10) + 15 = 185,

i did not see any reputation changes for the latest received up-votes.

Comment: Your answer is in Community Wiki mode, those don't generate reputation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a community wiki now, so you don't get any further reputation from the post. Given the nature of the post, I'm not inclined to remove the wiki either.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, i dont really understand that the rep stops, cause 97% of the post is still contributed by me. but oke :)

Comment: "It's a community wiki *now*" — did it get changed manually?  I thought that, as per [*Putting the Community back in Wiki*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/), auto conversions to community wiki were no more?

Comment: Oh, I'll answer mine own question.  The change happened back in February with revision 12, "added 15 characters in body; [made Community Wiki by 77120 editing at least 10 times]", but that was before the change.  It's just taken a while for @77120 to come around and ask about it. :)

Comment: I once did run into the same situation by editing my answer to often - what a bummer. It seems in April 2014 [all automatic Wiki conversion triggers from the software were removed](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/). I vote to add all reputation of all auto-wiki answers to the first author.

Based on the minor edits from two other authors i find your decision `Given the nature of the post` [closed as off-topic], you are `not inclined to remove the wiki either` as very off-putting.